# Any change is SMS inbox access policy in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Is it possible to access SMS inbox in iOS 7? Or intercepting message receives? I know it was not possible till iOS 6. But with new features in iOS 7, such as "Block Unwanted Phone Calls and Text Messages", I'm wondering how these new features are reflected in the iOS frameworks.

Comment: Everything is documented: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW1

Comment: Already reviewed. You mean if it's not there, there is no change?

Comment: Yes, there's no way to access messages without using private APIs.

Comment: What do you mean by private APIs?

Comment: Using methods from private frameworks but the app will be reject in the AppStore review process.

Comment: What about interception?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know enough about messaging private frameworks